# The infinite random walk: two approaches leads to two different solutions. How to solve?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

The "random walk" process is well known for mathematicians, see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk . It is also known as "the drunk walk".

It is demonstrated that if you have a n x n board (or even n x n .. .x n in higher dim boards) and move infinite number of steps, every square on board will be visited an infinite number times.

Now suppose you have also an infinite "n" square board and perform an infinite number of steps on it. Will every square on this board receive a visit? how many visits?

The first approach to solve this is supposing you already have an "infinite speed walker" running over finite n x n board , and then try to extend n to be infinite. In this case, every square will be visited infinite times, and so limit to infinite board shows it will be completely filled infinite times for every size of n.

The second approach is to suppose you already have an "infinite n board", and begin running a finite speed walker on it every time faster, extending speed to infinity. In this case, board will never be filled, because for every size of speed, will be always squares not visited.

Then the question (for me) remains open: how will look the behavior of infinite size board with an infinite speed walker into?

For me, this question is intriguing, because if this problem has no solution, then it shows that "time" can be created from "infinite speeds and sizes problems", since infinite speed walker will be always trying to solve the infinite size board, producing dynamic patterns into the board at every moment.

If you suppose a kind of mathematical "space" infinitely big and where things runs at random at infinite speed, very interesting things could appear into, for example "time", as happened in our universe.

Thanks for any idea

Miguel

Comment: Define "infinite speed"...

Comment: I suppose it could defined like "the time to move from a point to another in board is equal zero". But this also raise some questions, like "previous" and "next" probably will disappear. It is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

Your formalism is extremely messy compared to the usual formalism. In the more normal formalism, you just have a regular random walk on an infinite $n$-dimensional integer lattice. In an infinite number of time steps, every point is either visited finitely many (possibly $0$) times or infinitely many times, because the process is irreducible. Thus your question reduces to the question of whether the process is recurrent or transient. We actually know the answer: the process is recurrent when $n=1$ or $n=2$ and transient when $n \geq 3$. This is actually a deep fact which has ripples in seemingly unrelated subjects such as PDE involving the Laplacian.

Find a reference on infinite state space Markov chains for more details.

The rest of your question seems to really be more about scaling issues as you send the size of the lattice and the speed of the walker (or, equivalently, the time threshold for terminating the process) to infinity, rather than what happens when they are actually set equal to infinity. This is a considerably more complicated problem that's easier to address if you formulate it in a well-defined way (i.e. give a precise scaling relationship between, say, the size of the lattice and the termination time that you are interested in).

Comment: Ok, thanks I will try learn about transient processes.  I am not stochastic process expert, so I don´t know what level these subjects are studied. 

I will try refine some terms. Consider total board surface = 1 , then after k steps in n x n board the percent covered will be  $S = 1 - [(n^2-1)/n^2]^k$ . Considering 2x2 board gives S = 0 , 1/4 , 7/16 , 37/64 ..... . 

If we account k = nxn and tends n -> infinite, covered surface tends to 1 - 1/e (some 2/3 surface), so for "this infinite kind of steps and surfaces", it never will covered.

Comment: @MiguelVelilla But now you've imposed a scaling constraint on the size vs. time. With a higher time:size ratio, you might have a different outcome in the limit.

Comment: Thanks and yes, I noticed am imposing constraint by attaching "k" to "n", thats to say, both of them "tends to infinite" at one depending on "n". I also note that whatever "k" I use, always I could relate "k" to "n" via some function k = f(n) and so final painted surface also would go to some function g(e). 

For instance suppose I say ok lets $k = f(n) = n^n$ but $n^n = n^2.n^{(n-2)}$ and $g(e) -> 1-(1/e)^{(n^(n-2))}$ . This also leads to final "incomplete board" like previous one, although almost fully painted for every "n".

Comment: By using $k=n^2$, it is interesanting to imagine what an observer should see on the board. When it reaches "infinite", the filled surface shuld also reach exactly 1-1/e (I really can´t figure what is 1-1/e part of infinite). From this point, the walker should step on his feet exactly over already marked squares, not to bypass the mathematical limit imposed. 

That´s is impossible because the random nature imposed initially to the problem.

Comment: The other way to face problem is the one I mentioned initially separating completely k and n.  a) you already have an infinite walker on finite board NxN and tends N -> infinite or b) you already have an infinite board NxN and try a finite walker to walk every time faster. This also leads to nonsense.

I know the risk of working with infinites, so at some point I probably am making wrong assumptions.